# Multipeer Connectivity with personal Hotspot not working

Tags: ios, swift, connectivity, multipeer-connectivity

I am working with Multipeer connectivity. It works fine when all devices are connected to same wifi.

I have 1 master and 5 slaves devices . I want to do connectivity with personal hotspot but everytime the connection will declined.

**This is my code :**

```
class SessionManager: NSObject, MCSessionDelegate, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate {

    func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String: String] ? ) {
        browser.invitePeer(peerID, to: mcSession, withContext: nil, timeout: 10)
    }

    func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, lostPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        print("Lost Peer")
    }


    static
    let shared = SessionManager()

    var peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
    var mcSession: MCSession!
        var mcAdvertiserAssistant: MCAdvertiserAssistant!
            var delegate: SessionDelegate!
                var serviceBrowser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser
    var serviceAdvertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser

    override init() {
        serviceBrowser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: peerID, serviceType: "demo")
        serviceAdvertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peerID, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: "demo")

        super.init()

        peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
        mcSession = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .required)
        mcSession.delegate = self

        serviceBrowser.delegate = self
        serviceBrowser.startBrowsingForPeers()
        serviceAdvertiser.delegate = self
        serviceAdvertiser.startAdvertisingPeer()

    }


    //MARK: Start Hosting
    func startHosting() {
        mcAdvertiserAssistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "demo", discoveryInfo: nil, session: mcSession)
        mcAdvertiserAssistant.start()
    }

    //MARK: Join Session
    func joinSession() {
        let mcBrowser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "demo", session: mcSession)
        mcBrowser.delegate = self
        mcBrowser.navigationController ? .navigationBar.backgroundColor = .black
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .black
        UIApplication.visibleViewController.present(mcBrowser, animated: true)
    }

    //MARK: Delegate Methods
    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {}

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {}

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL ? , withError error : Error ? ) {}

    func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        UIApplication.visibleViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        UIApplication.visibleViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
        switch state {
            case MCSessionState.connected:
                print("Connected:SessionManager \(peerID.displayName)")

            case MCSessionState.connecting:
                print("Connecting:SessionManager \(peerID.displayName)")

            case MCSessionState.notConnected:
                print("Not Connected:SessionManager \(peerID.displayName)")
        }
    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        let sessionData = SessionModel.init(session, peerID, data)
        delegate.didRecieveSessionData(sessionData)
    }

    func advertiser(_ advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: Data ? , invitationHandler : @escaping(Bool, MCSession ? ) - > Void) {
        print("Receive Invitation")
        invitationHandler(true, self.mcSession)
    }
    func advertiser(_ advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didNotStartAdvertisingPeer error: Error) {
        print("Ddn't Start")
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem as you, it times out when connecting. However I can use internet on the slave without problems.

Comment: Not yet...
But it can work when all device wifi is on and remains unconnected.