# Multipeer Connectivity With Personal Hotspot Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multipeer-connectivity

I am working with Multipeer connectivity. It works fine when all devices are connected to same wifi.

I have 1 master and 5 slaves devices. I want to do connectivity with personal hotspot but everytime the connection will declined.
I want to connect all slaves devices with master device using personal hotspot to share data between them.

**This is my code :**

```
class SessionManager: NSObject, MCSessionDelegate, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate {

    func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String: String] ? ) {
        browser.invitePeer(peerID, to: mcSession, withContext: nil, timeout: 10)
    }

    func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, lostPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        print("Lost Peer")
    }


    static
    let shared = SessionManager()

    var peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
    var mcSession: MCSession!
        var mcAdvertiserAssistant: MCAdvertiserAssistant!
            var delegate: SessionDelegate!
                var serviceBrowser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser
    var serviceAdvertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser

    override init() {
        serviceBrowser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: peerID, serviceType: "demo")
        serviceAdvertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peerID, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: "demo")

        super.init()

        peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
        mcSession = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .required)
        mcSession.delegate = self

        serviceBrowser.delegate = self
        serviceBrowser.startBrowsingForPeers()
        serviceAdvertiser.delegate = self
        serviceAdvertiser.startAdvertisingPeer()

    }


    //MARK: Start Hosting
    func startHosting() {
        mcAdvertiserAssistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "demo", discoveryInfo: nil, session: mcSession)
        mcAdvertiserAssistant.start()
    }

    //MARK: Join Session
    func joinSession() {
        let mcBrowser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "demo", session: mcSession)
        mcBrowser.delegate = self
        mcBrowser.navigationController ? .navigationBar.backgroundColor = .black
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .black
        UIApplication.visibleViewController.present(mcBrowser, animated: true)
    }

    //MARK: Delegate Methods
    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {}

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {}

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL ? , withError error : Error ? ) {}

    func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        UIApplication.visibleViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        UIApplication.visibleViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
        switch state {
            case MCSessionState.connected:
                print("Connected:SessionManager \(peerID.displayName)")

            case MCSessionState.connecting:
                print("Connecting:SessionManager \(peerID.displayName)")

            case MCSessionState.notConnected:
                print("Not Connected:SessionManager \(peerID.displayName)")
        }
    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        let sessionData = SessionModel.init(session, peerID, data)
        delegate.didRecieveSessionData(sessionData)
    }

    func advertiser(_ advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: Data ? , invitationHandler : @escaping(Bool, MCSession ? ) - > Void) {
        print("Receive Invitation")
        invitationHandler(true, self.mcSession)
    }
    func advertiser(_ advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didNotStartAdvertisingPeer error: Error) {
        print("Ddn't Start")
    }


}
```

Is there any way to do this thing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was already asked before (to no avail): [Multipeer Connectivity with personal Hotspot not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51593275/multipeer-connectivity-with-personal-hotspot-not-working)

As far as I know MPC is just an abstraction layer on top of different ways of networking. Apple uses M-DNS (Bonjour) and other techniques including Bluetooth to make networking between macOS / iOS devices as easy as possible.

Multipeer connectivity is a peer-to-peer solution and what you are describing is much more a client-server solution. That does not mean you can't pull it off but it is good to keep this in mind! This means that you want MPC as a basic level of networking and implement a client-server structure on top of that. I don't see any reason why that would not be possible when using one of the devices as a hotspot but I don't think that is even needed: Airdrop also uses MCP and it works also when devices are not in the same network.

There are some valuable resources on this:

- https://www1.in.tum.de/lehrstuhl_1/teaching/tutorials/508-sgd-ws13-tutorial-multiplayer-games
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity
- https://www.appcoda.com/chat-app-swift-tutorial/

Comment: Can you please provide me the code for the same for the latest x-code 10.1 or 10.0 

As i'm trying to work on the links provided by you. It seems to much error and crashes.

Comment: I have added and example from my lecture on it in last October (Swift 4.2), it is not exactly what you need but explains a lot about Multi Peer Connectivity, hope that helps! https://github.com/jakorten/MPC

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm having the same issue, it's not really client server at all - just because one device is supplying the internet connection, does not mean you don't also want to treat some apps as peer to peer between those two devices, within that network... one thing I have verified that does work is two devices running multiplier tethered to a third device.